# Why does jQuery selected collect duplicate elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple grid of li elements that I have made selectable.  I then iterate over them once the selection is complete.  But the collection of elements appears to be a set of duplicates when you select more than 1 box in the grid.  What is going on here?

[Example can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdoering/xrPHE/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the selected function is being called multiple times, once for each selected element in fact.

I've modified your code to see this:

```
elements = $('.ui-selected');
console.log(elements);
```

From the documentation at http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/ it suggests that "This event is triggered at the end of the select operation, on each element added to the selection." so what you are seeing is the expected behaviour.

I think what you want is the 'stop' event:

```
$("#selectableGrid").selectable({
    stop: function() {
        elements = $('.ui-selected');
        elements.each(function(idx, item) {
            alert($(item).position().top);
        });
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding to the `selected` event, try binding to the `stop` event like this:

```
stop: function() {
    elements = null;
    elements = $('.ui-selected');
    elements.each(function(idx, item) {
        alert($(item).position().top);

    });
}
```

The selected event will fire once for each item you select, and then your function will also run each time, thereby building on the list of selected items. By using the stop event instead, the function runs only once per selected item.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xrPHE/5/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Your `selected` callback is being invoked once for each selected item. Within that callback, you are then querying for all of the selected items, and alerting for each of them.

The end result is that when when you select, e.g., 2 items, your `selected` callback is invoked for the first item, and you get a single alert for that item. Then your callback is invoked for the second item, at which time there are now two items selected, and you now get 2 more alerts (for 3 total). With a 3rd item selected, you get 6 alerts, and so on.

Anyway, that's the *why* part of it, with regards to the behavior you're seeing. Check out @j08691's answer for a solution that shows the behavior you were probably going for.